# Get html code into string C# when need account authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, credentials, webrequest

I want to download webpage code (plug.dj) and paste it into string. It is not hard but when I test my program an error appeared.

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I think I cannot download code because I am not logged on this website. I tried add credentials into my code but I have no idea how it should looks like. User can log in with Google, Facebook or Twitter.

My code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://plug.dj/drum-bass/");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (**Here should be username**, **Password**);
request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Know someone how to solve this?

I got idea how to solve it but I dont know if it is realisable. Maybe could this program using data of web browser and get this information by this way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only want to download a **public/anonymous-login** page of this website, I can't see any reason why you need to pass user-credentials or get `401` error code - *no* authentication in needed.

I just tried it at my end and it is working as desired:

```
using System.Net;
//...
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://plug.dj");
}
```

Results:

```
<!doctype html><!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"><![endif]--><!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>plug.dj &ndash;&nbsp;</title><link rel="icon" ...
```

Comment: Yes, but I need download page on this site where I have to be logged in. On this page are rooms and you need authentication to access them.
For example http://plug.dj/drum-bass